# Use Universal Image Loader in combination with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, universal-image-loader

Hello fellow Android coders

**Problem**

I need to download 50 images. The problem is, that the user can't use the app while they are downloading and it is bad for the user's experience.

**Intention**

I thought it would be a good idea, to use Universal Image Loader to download the images while using the app. The problem I have now is that I don't know how to use it together with AsyncTask. I'm using AsyncTask because I'm only loading the first 10 Results and then, when the user scrolls to the end of the code it loads the next 10 results.

I'm using an AsyncTask inside a Fragment for that.

**Problem encountering**

The problem I'm encountering is how to implement the Universal Image Loader correctly

**Approach**

What I did so far is to add the ImageLoader library to libs and add it as a library. Then, I created a new class with this content

```
package de.activevalue.ttflies;

import android.app.Application;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: pan
 * Date: 28.10.13
 * Time: 10:11
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this configuration
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
}
```

Then, I also edit the Android Manifest XML by adding this line `android:name=".MyApplication"` into the `<application ...` tag of the XML file. I didn't add it as an Activity. I added it just as a name.

But now I'm encountering a problem. The documentation states to use it like that if I understood it correctly

`imageLoader.loadImage(imageURL, ImageView)`

The problem here is, that I can't use this in the doInBackground method since I can't change the layout there. So I would have to do that in the onPostExecute method, but I'm encountering problems. So I would like to hear a solution on how to use this Universal Image Loader in combination with an AsyncTask in Android.

As I said I included the libraries, edited the Android Manifest file and created a class for the Application. But what now?

What do I put in the onCreate method of the Fragment? Where do I initialize the imageLoader? I don't really know where to do what in my class/Fragment, where I need the imageLoader.

Any suggestions on how I could solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is my Application Class :

```
public class UILApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you
        // may tune some of them,
        // or you can create default configuration by
        // ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
        // method.
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                .build();
        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
```

// My Activity :

Created object for the image loader :

```
private ImageLoader imageLoader = null;
```

I am updating the UI in handler as follows :

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case SET_ADAPTER:
imageLoader.displayImage(my URL, ImageView to show , Utils.options);


mHandler.removeMessages(SET_ADAPTER);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        };
    };
```

and finally my Utils class. the options are,

```
public static DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
```

It is working fine for me. Universal image loader provides such a good quality image rather than other library.